# Why after my ajax basic auth, browser wants password from user?

Tags: jquery, ajax, authentication

I want to authorise user with javascript. I am doing it with ajax. Ajax basic auth is good and success fucntion works well, but after it I have got redirect, where browser asks users about login and password. How I can solve it?

```
$('#btnlogin').click(function(){
    var username = $("input#userlogin").val();
    var password = $("input#userpassword").val();  

    $.ajax
    ({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/cloud/",
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
      },

      success: function(){
        console.log('ok');
        setTimeout(function() { window.location = '/cloud/'; }, 2000);
      },

      error: function(){
        alert('wrong password');
      }
    });

});
```

Comment: Copy please the /cloud/index file for us please

Comment: there is php file and we have got there apache basic authorisation, I can't give it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Answer (score 0):

I think the browser only caches the credentials if it prompted the user for them itself. If the credentials are sent by Javascript, the browser doesn't save them. So when the user goes to a page normally, instead of accessing it via AJAX, the browser will prompt them for the credentials.

I've done some searching, and as far as I can tell there's no way in Javascript to save the credentials to the browser's cache.

What you should do is set a session variable when the user logs in. Other pages should check for the session variable before requiring HTTP authentication.